# File upload in Testcafe with hidden input

Tags: javascript, file-upload, e2e-testing, testcafe, multifile-uploader

I want to test upload folder/ multiple files using `testcafe`. It has couple of steps to upload files.

- Step - 1: Click on file browse button to select files
- Step - 2: Native Confirmation box to confirm the Upload
- Step - 3: Click on Upload button to upload files

In the HTML code, input [type=file] is hidden. 
HTML Code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-exec" value="Select Files" id="fileBrowseBtn">
    <input type="file" id="selectFiles" webkitdirectory="" style="display: none">
</div>
```

I tried with the following code but was not working at all.

```
 await t
.click(Selector('#fileBrowseBtn'))
.setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
.setFilesToUpload(Selector('input').withAttribute('type','file'), [
            './uploads/1.jpg',
            './uploads/2.jpg',
            './uploads/3.jpg'
        ])
.setNativeDialogHandler(() => true)
.click(Selector('#uploadWizard').find('button').withText('Upload'))
```

Can anyone help me with workable example? I tried lots but may be I missed something. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

According to [an example](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/upload.html#populate-file-upload-input), you should not open the 'Choose file' dialog.

Try to simplify your code as follows:

```js
await t
.setFilesToUpload(Selector('input').withAttribute('type','file'), [
            './uploads/1.jpg',
            './uploads/2.jpg',
            './uploads/3.jpg'
        ])
.click(Selector('#uploadWizard').find('button').withText('Upload'))
```

Comment: You can see a detailed [description](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/basics/test-file-upload.html) of how to test file upload in TestCafe and inspect a runnable example [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/tree/master/examples/upload-files).